# Async process blocking R Shiny app

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny

It should be possible to use the R packages `future` and `promises` to trigger asynchronous (long running) processing via Shiny apps without freezing the rest of the app while the async process is running in another R process.

See:

```
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/intro.html
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/overview.html
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/futures.html
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/shiny.html
```

I got this to work in R-script-based environment but can't get this to work when I implement a simple shiny app with 2 functions. The "not-async" function is always blocked while the async function is running, but that should not be the case.

I have posted the same question on the GitHub repo of the package `promises`: https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23

I am posting it here as well hoping someone can help.

The question is:

1. Can you take a look at the shiny app example posted below and let me know why the async processing is blocking the app? (It should not block).
2. Ideally, can you provide a small example of an app with a non-blocking async and normal functionality (accessible while the async is running)?

### Environment

Mac OS 10.12

```
$ R --version
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"

remove.packages("future")
remove.packages("promises")
remove.packages("shiny")

install.packages("future")
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/promises")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/shiny")

> packageVersion("future")
[1] ‘1.8.1’
> packageVersion("promises")
[1] ‘1.0.1’
> packageVersion("shiny")
[1] ‘1.0.5.9000’
```

One side question on the shiny package version, https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/intro.html says it should be >=1.1, but even installing with devtools, the version remains 1.0.5... . Is this an issue or is there a typo in the doc?

> First, you can use promises with Shiny outputs. If you’re using an async-compatible version of Shiny (version >=1.1), all of the built-in renderXXX functions can deal with either regular values or promises.

### Example of issue

I have implemented this simple shiny app inspired from the example at the URLs mentioned above.
The shiny app has 2 "sections":

1. A button to trigger the "long running" async processing. This is simulated by a function `read_csv_async` which sleeps for a few seconds, reads a csv file into a data frame. The df is then rendered below the button.
2. A simple functionality which should work at any time (including when the async processing has been triggered): it includes a slider defining a number of random values to be generated. We then render a histogram of these values.

The issue is that the second functionality (histogram plot update) is blocked while the async processing is occurring.

global.R

```
library("shiny")
library("promises")
library("dplyr")
library("future")

# path containing all files, including ui.R and server.R
setwd("/path/to/my/shiny/app/dir")   

plan(multiprocess)

# A function to simulate a long running process
read_csv_async = function(sleep, path){
      log_path = "./mylog.log"
      pid = Sys.getpid()
      write(x = paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "pid:", pid, "Async process started"), file = log_path, append = TRUE)
      Sys.sleep(sleep)
      df = read.csv(path)
      write(x = paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "pid:", pid, "Async process work completed\n"), file = log_path, append = TRUE)
      df
}
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "submit_and_retrieve", label = "Submit short async analysis"),
  br(),
  br(),
  tableOutput("user_content"),

  br(),
  br(),
  br(),
  hr(),

  sliderInput(inputId = "hist_slider_val",
              label = "Histogram slider",
              value = 25, 
              min = 1,
              max = 100),

  plotOutput("userHist")
)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output){
    # When button is clicked
    # load csv asynchronously and render table
    data_promise = eventReactive(input$submit_and_retrieve, {
        future({ read_csv_async(10, "./data.csv") }) 
    })
   output$user_content <- renderTable({
     data_promise() %...>% head(5)
    })


  # Render a new histogram 
  # every time the slider is moved
  output$userHist = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$hist_slider_val))
  })
}
```

data.csv

```
Column1,Column2
foo,2
bar,5
baz,0
```

Thanks!

Comment: For your side question, I'm guessing that's a "cart before the horse" problem, meaning that they documented the need for 1.1 before it's available. You can find it here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/v1.1.0-rc

Comment: OK, this could make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So this behavior is normal, see the response of the package developer at  https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23

**Summary:**

In shiny apps, one R process can be shared by multiple users.
If one user submits a long running task, then all the other users sharing the same underlying R process are blocked.
The goal of `promises` is to avoid this. So `promises` will prevent blocking between "user sessions" within one R process but not within a single "user session".

The author of the package mentioned that this feature is not supported *yet* and that it may be added if enough people ask for it. If you are looking for this, please go the GitHub issue and like the original question - this is how interest for new features is measured.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As this or similar questions about shiny intra-session responsiveness are [frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913050/how-to-make-an-operation-uninterruptible-in-r-shiny/) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844507/how-do-i-wrap-a-blocking-function-into-a-promise-rshiny) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474545/unable-to-render-loading-using-shiny-and-futures/) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407004/shiny-promises-future-is-not-working-on-eventreactive) I think it's worth mentioning the workaround **Joe Cheng** provides in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23) @Raphvanns created:

> If you really must have this kind of behavior, there is a way to work
>   around it. You can "hide" the async operation from the Shiny session
>   (allowing the session to move on with its event loop) **by not returning
>   your promise chain from your observer/reactive code**. Essentially the
>   async operation becomes a "fire and forget". You need to hook up a
>   promise handler to have some side effect; in the example below, I set
>   a reactiveVal on successful completion.
>
> Some caveats to this approach:
>
> 1. By doing this you are **inherently opening yourself up to race
>      conditions.** Even in this very simple example, the user can click the
>      Submit button multiple times; if the long-running task has very
>      variable runtime you might end up with multiple results coming back,
>      but out of order. Or if you reference `input` values in promise
>      handlers, they might pick up values that were set after the submit
>      button was clicked!
> 2. You also lose the automatic semi-transparent
>      indication that an output has been invalidated (though below I at
>      least null the `reactiveVal` out in the beginning of the `observeEvent`).

Accordingly the solution for the above example code can be something like this:

```
library("shiny")
library("promises")
library("dplyr")
library("future")

# path containing all files, including ui.R and server.R
# setwd("/path/to/my/shiny/app/dir")

write.csv(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     Column1 = c("foo", "bar", "baz"),
                     Column2 = c(2, 5, 0)
), file = "./data.csv")

onStop(function() {
  file.remove("./data.csv")
})

plan(multiprocess)

# A function to simulate a long running process
read_csv_async = function(sleep, path){
  log_path = "./mylog.log"
  pid = Sys.getpid()
  write(x = paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "pid:", pid, "Async process started"), file = log_path, append = TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(sleep)
  df = read.csv(path)
  write(x = paste(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "pid:", pid, "Async process work completed\n"), file = log_path, append = TRUE)
  df
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("parallel"),
  sliderInput(inputId = "hist_slider_val",
              label = "Histogram slider",
              value = 25, 
              min = 1,
              max = 100),
  plotOutput("userHist"),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit_and_retrieve", label = "Submit short async analysis"),
  tableOutput("user_content")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_promise <- reactiveVal()

  # When button is clicked
  # load csv asynchronously and render table
  observeEvent(input$submit_and_retrieve, {
    future({ read_csv_async(10, "./data.csv") }) %...>% data_promise()
    return(NULL) # hide future
  })

  output$user_content <- renderTable({
    req(data_promise())
    head(data_promise(), 5)
  })

  # Render a new histogram 
  # every time the slider is moved
  output$userHist = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$hist_slider_val))
  })

  output$parallel <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(300)
    paste("Something running in parallel:", Sys.time())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note the `return(NULL)` in the `observeEvent` call to hide the future. This way the long running process no longer blocks the execution of the other reactives.