# How to make an operation uninterruptible in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app I have a output which should update itself continuously. But whenever I execute a long-running calculation, the output is just paused. My question is: how to make the output runs continuously and uninterruptible?

Please see the short demo below:
The clock refreshes every one second, but if I click the button which runs for 5 seconds, the clock is paused.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("button","Expensive calcualtion(takes 5 seconds)"),
    tags$p("Current Time:"),
    textOutput("time"),
    tags$p("Result from clicking button:"),
    textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$time <- renderText({
        invalidateLater(1000)
        as.character(Sys.time())
    })

    observeEvent(input$button,{
        Sys.sleep(5)
        output$result <- renderText(runif(1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to use `future` and `promises` to make the long-running process runs asynchronously, but it doesn't work. Where is wrong? And is there a better way for achieving this purpose?

```r
library(shiny)
library(future)
library(promises)
plan("multisession")

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("button","Expensive calcualtion(takes 5 seconds)"),
    tags$p("Current Time:"),
    textOutput("time"),
    tags$p("Result from clicking button:"),
    textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$time <- renderText({
        invalidateLater(1000)
        as.character(Sys.time())
    })

    process <- eventReactive(input$button,{
        future({
            Sys.sleep(5)
            runif(1)
        })
    })

    output$result <- renderText(process())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This might help - [Shiny promises future is not working on eventReactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407004/shiny-promises-future-is-not-working-on-eventreactive)

Comment: This question finally made me read up on async programming in Shiny. This seems like expected behavior. As per Joe Cheng's [response](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23) on github - *"The goal, at least for this release of Shiny, is not to allow this kind of intra-session responsiveness, but rather, inter-session; i.e., running an async operation won't make its owning session more responsive, but rather will allow other sessions to be more responsive."* Also see - [Async process blocking R Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165443/async-process-blocking-r-shiny-app)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That response is very useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I wrap a blocking function into a promise RShiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844507/how-do-i-wrap-a-blocking-function-into-a-promise-rshiny)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Shree for pointing out the solution. After reading the [response](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23) from Joe Cheng. It seems like the key is to:

> Hide the async operation from Shiny by not having the promise be the last expression.

The problem is resolved by creating a reactive value and assign the promise to it in `observeEvent` as the side effect.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$time <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    as.character(Sys.time())
  })

  process <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    output$isbusy <- renderText("busy") # a simple busy indicator
    future({
      Sys.sleep(5)
      runif(1)
    }) %...>%
      process()
    # Hide the async operation from Shiny by not having the promise be the last expression
    NULL # important
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    output$isbusy <- renderText("") # a simple busy indicator
    process()
  })
}
```

Comment: This is great! +1. I edited the code a bit to make it simpler. Feel free to rollback if you disagree. And if you agree, I'd suggest updating the server code in the question as well so that answer and question are similar.

Comment: Just modified my question so it's consistent with the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! I suggested the edit only because I expect this question to get many hits so it is nice to have the code in a to-the-point concise format.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that this approach may cause race conditions if used the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that **Sys.sleep()** suspends the execution of R expression. You can use things like the **delay()** function from **shinyjs**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), #You have to add this.
  actionButton("button","Expensive calcualtion(takes 5 seconds)"),
  tags$p("Current Time:"),
  textOutput("time"),
  tags$p("Result from clicking button:"),
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  timer <- reactiveTimer(500)
  current_time <- reactive({
  timer()
  as.character(Sys.time())
 })
 output$time <- renderText(current_time())

 observeEvent(input$button,{
 delay(5000, output$result <- renderText("result"))
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think `Sys.sleep()` only represents a costly computation and not trying to introduce a delay. `delay()` may not not help with this. Great to learn about `delay()` though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. `shinyjs::delay()` seems to work because it executes JavaScript on client side. But the expensive calculation happens in the server. Please try replace the `Sys.sleep()` with `eigen(matrix(runif(1e6), ncol=1000, nrow=1000))[1]$values[1]
` which is expensive and takes a few seconds.